# intermediate values of counter

Tags: javascript, angularjs

please help to fix the script. http://jsfiddle.net/k9r4t/

when hovering. button_hover increasing the value of the counter. but the value of the counter is displayed on the screen when the cursor leaves the. button_hover. and the user sees only the initial and final value of the counter.

I would like the user to see the intermediate values

controller code:

```
var app = angular.module("moduleCounter", []);

app.controller("controllerCounter", function ($scope){
    $scope.counter = 0;

    $scope.incrementCounter = function(){
        $scope.startNext = setInterval(function(){
            $scope.counter++;
        }, 400);
    }

    $scope.stopCounter = function(){
        clearInterval($scope.startNext);
    }   
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use [`$timeout`](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng.%24timeout) , it is Angular's native service:

```
var app = angular.module("moduleCounter", []);

app.controller("controllerCounter", function ($scope , $timeout){
    $scope.counter = 0;

    $scope.incrementCounter = function(){
       $scope.setTimeout();
    }

    $scope.setTimeout = function(){
       $scope.startNext = $timeout( $scope.counterUp , 400);
    }

    $scope.counterUp = function(){
       $scope.counter++;
       $scope.setTimeout();
    }

    $scope.stopCounter = function(){
       $timeout.cancel($scope.startNext);
    }   
});
```

JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/cherniv/k9r4t/1/